# Parsing from an XML file

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

How can I parse lat and long value in jQuery from a php file that outputs this:

```
<gps>
    <loc lat="42.6438" lon="21.9275" alt="29.7" spd="0" dir="342" cep="203.1" upd="2013-03-09 02:10:31"/>
</gps>
```

UPDATE! 
This is my full code in head.php

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "gps-tracking/track.xml",
            dataType:'data',
            complete: function(data){
                    var loc = $("loc");
                    var lat = loc.attr("lat");
                    var lon = loc.attr("lon");
                    console.log(data);
                    console.log(lat);
            }
        });
```

console.log(data); outputs this:

```
Object { readyState= 4 , responseXML=document, responseText= "<gps><loc lat="40.6438"...03-09 02:10:31"/></gps>" , more...}
```

console.log(lat); outputs: undefined!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually your code:

```
complete: function(data){
                    var loc = $("loc");
                    var lat = loc.attr("lat");
                    var lon = loc.attr("lon");
                    alert (lat);
            }
```

Tries to store a Dom element "loc" into the var loc. First of all you should try to use the data of your complete function, because there your php values are stored.

Then try to create a DOM element like `$(data).children('loc').attr('lat');`

Small demo fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/P6JVw/

And here the code you should use:

```
complete: function(data){
                        var xmlObj = $(data.responseText).children('loc');
                        var loc = xmlObj.attr('loc');
                        var lat = xmlObj.attr('lat');
                        var lon = xmlObj.attr('lon');;
                        alert (lat);
                }
```

Comment: Its weird but i still get undefined!

Comment: For testing how data looks like, do a console.log(data); and add the results at your first post. Maybe there is a problem at the ajax request.

Comment: I got this on console.log(data); `Object { readyState=

4

, responseXML=document, responseText=

"<gps><loc lat="40.6438"...03-09 02:10:31"/></gps>"

, more...}`

Comment: and with console.log(lat); i always get undefined :(

Comment: I've updated my code, only take the responseText of data Object.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty straightforward. Just call `attr()`

```
var loc = $("loc");
var lat = loc.attr("lat");
var lon = loc.attr("lon");
```